# On Hochschild cohomology

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let given a ring $A$ without zero divizors and torsion free as $\mathbb{Z}$- module. Let also given $M~-$ $A~-$ bimodule which is torsion as module over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Is it true that if $A$ has finite rank, then $HH^i(A, M)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} = 0$ for every integer $i\geq 0$?

Where $HH^i(A, -)$ means Hochschild cohomology.

Note that this fact is generalization of [Beuemont-Pierce Principle Theorem](https://books.google.ru/books?id=StEcCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=Beaumont-Pierce+Principal+Theorem&source=bl&ots=XNLvo_IfMP&sig=pynkwdXTy3mpzYasiVMMldc8RNA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW59Cx2_vPAhWMFywKHYEaAxEQ6AEIKDAE#v=onepage&q=Beaumont-Pierce%20Principal%20Theorem&f=false).

Comment: If $M=A$ then $HH^1=Z(A)$, so any commutative finite-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra gives a counterexample.

Comment: In Your case $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} =M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}  = 0$, but I considered $A$ without torsion.

Comment: No, take, for instance, $A=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: No, if $M=A$ then $HH^0=Z(A)$.  And the question makes sense for $i>0$.

Comment: Sorry I forget about condition $M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} : = 0$.

Comment: Is $A$ supposed to be commutative?

Comment: No, I want noncommutative $A$.

Comment: @LeonidPositselski Sure, I made a typo. With the new condition isn't the Hochschild complex already zero $\otimes\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I think it isn't.

Comment: Well, $(M\otimes_A\dots\otimes_A M)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}=0$ becuase $M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}=0$

Comment: Defenition of $HH^i$'s see here : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochschild_homology . @SashaP Your comment doesn't help.

Comment: I am referring to the Hochschild cochain complex, see Weibel's book.